# the execution process for select statment in sql where same tablename specified in WHERE CONDITION cluase

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
Select DISTINCT E.EmpID, E.EmpFname, E.Department 
FROM EmployeesInfo E, Employeesinfo e1
WHERE E.Department = E1.Department AND E.EmpID != E1.EmpID;
```

How will this command be executed? Is it  same way where correleated sub-queries are executed like top down approach?

Whenever in the condition we used the table name of select statement like above example the process of execution is like correlated sub-queires i.e top down approach?

How different these commands are executed from normal select from tablenmame where condition process?

Comment: Which is your DBMS : MySQL or SQL-Server ? Tag only one of them please.

Comment: Top down  ??   what do you mean ?? SQL is not a procedural language  but a descriptive language then top donw  is not properly applicable ..  and you have not subquery in your code  but only a single query .

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Usually joins will work faster than inner queries, but in reality it will depend on the execution plan generated by SQL Server. No matter how you write your query, SQL Server will always transform it on an execution plan. If it is "smart" enough to generate the same plan from both queries, you will get the same result.

For your Case :

```
Select DISTINCT E.EmpID, E.EmpFname, E.Department 
FROM EmployeesInfo E, Employeesinfo e1
WHERE E.Department = E1.Department AND E.EmpID != E1.EmpID;
```

This is a similar way of using **INNER JOIN** Syntax. So it works faster instead of using this in **SUB Query**.